# VueJS - array with Edm.DateTime Elements, transform dates and show them in table

Tags: vue.js, date

Got following .json:

```
[{
"DATE": "/Date(1511346375000)/",
"POSID": "1"
},
{
"DATE": "/Date(1511346375000)/",
"POSID": "2"
}
}]
```

I'm loading the unique values in my table via v-for:

```
  <tr v-for="(value, key) in countDates">
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
     </tr>
```

Thing is, I want to display the readable Date like:
2017-11-23

So I have to remove the "/" and convert it in a UTC-Formatted-Date.

Can I achieve that via computed properties?
Or is there another possibility?

Comment: Like this? https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/qVKOoX?editors=1010

Comment: You could write a computed property, where you return a modified version of your array or you could just define a method which converts the date and call this method within your repeating template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  convertDate1 (value) {
    if (value === 'null') {
      return value.replace('null', 'no date specified')
    } else {
      var d = new Date(parseInt(value.replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', ''), 10))
    }
    var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1  // months from 1-12
    var day = d.getUTCDate()
    var year = d.getUTCFullYear()
    return year + '/' + month + '/' + day
  }
```

+

```
<td>{{ convertDate1(value.key) }}</td>
```